# Firebase Cloud Messaging Failing to Retrieve Instance ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

this is my first question on Stack Overflow!

I am trying to deploy my firebase application on the firebase server using the ' firebase deploy' command. While running the "messaging" example [provided by Firebase] on my local machine, I have no issues generating an instance ID. However, when I deploy the application on the Firebase server and run the app in the browser, the application is not able to retrieve the Instance ID from the FCM server. This is a snippet of the response that I am getting from the Chrome console:

```
No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.
(index):226 Requesting permission...
(index):239 Unable to get permission to notify.  V
(index):226 Requesting permission...
(index):239 Unable to get permission to notify.  V {code: 

    "messaging/permission-blocked", 
    message: "Messaging: The required permissions were not grant… blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked)."}
code: "messaging/permission-blocked"message: "Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked)."stack: (...) ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you haven't [request permission to receive notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#request_permission_to_receive_notifications):

> The method `messaging.requestPermission()` displays a consent dialog to let users grant your app permission to receive notifications in the browser. If permission is denied, FCM registration token requests result in an error.
>
> ```
> messaging.requestPermission()
> .then(function() {
>   console.log('Notification permission granted.');
>   // TODO(developer): Retrieve a Instance ID token for use with FCM.
>   // ...
> })
> .catch(function(err) {
>   console.log('Unable to get permission to notify. ', err);
> });
> ```

Comment: I don't see the dialog either

Comment: If the dialog is not shown, try to minimize and maximize the Chrome window. After that the dialog was shown